# Using function's return value in if statement

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Hopefully a quick question here.

Can you use a function's returned value in a if statement? I.e.

```
function queryThis(request) {

  return false;

}

if(queryThis('foo') != false) { doThat(); }
```

Very simple and obvious I'm sure, but I'm running into a number of problems with syntax errors and I can't identify the problem.

Comment: looks right to me, though I would use `!== false` instead.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the problematic code with the syntax errors instead of this simple example that you could easily test for yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use

```
if(queryThis('foo')) { doThat(); }

function queryThis(parameter) {
    // some code
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Also interesting: why is `return` from `if` not possible as in [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#if-and-unless)

Comment: @Timo What do you mean by `not possible`? You can do `if (some_check) { return 1; } else { return 0; }`? Is it some kind of comment for advertise the other language?

Comment: It is not related to the question, the ternary op is what I was looking for: `x = true?1:2`

Comment: @Timo, oh, ok, sorry, didn't understand that first time.

Answer (score 5):

Not only you can use functions in `if` statements in JavaScript, but in almost all programming languages you can do that. This case is specially bold in JavaScript, as in it, functions are prime citizens. Functions are almost everything in JavaScript. Function is object, function is interface, function is return value of another function, function could be a parameter, function creates closures, etc. Therefore, this is 100% valid.

You can run this example in Firebug to see that it's working.

```
var validator = function (input) {
    return Boolean(input);
}

if (validator('')) {
    alert('true is returned from function'); 
}
if (validator('something')) {
    alert('true is returned from function'); 
}
```

Also as a hint, why using **comparison operators** in `if` block when we know that the expression is a Boolean expression?

Answer (score 3):

In sort, yes you can. If you know it is going to return a boolean you can even make it a bit simpler:

```
if ( isBar("foo") ) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem. I don't see anything wrong with the syntax either.
To make sure you could catch the return value in a variable and see if that solves your problem.
That would also make it easier to inspect what came back from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can provided it returns a boolean in your example.