# What is return in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

What is return in JavaScript ? And what is advantage of using return function ? I can also get 16 by doing this --

```
var number = function ( ok ){
confirm( 8 * ok );
}
number(2);
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____…

So, What is the advantage of using return function ?

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {
return number * 2;
};

var newNumber = timesTwo (8);
confirm(newNumber);
```

BTW, is return used for Ex :---->

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {
return number * 2;
};

var newNumber = timesTwo (8);

if ( newNumber === 16 ){
confirm("success");
}

else{
confirm("failure");
}
```

Am i right ? because i think only function can't be used for If-Else or any other code,so return used ??

Answer (score 2):

`return` is used so that a function can return a value to its caller. If `return` is not used like this, then the programmer has to use global variables to pass a computed value from a function to its caller, which is bad. Also, `return` is not a function.

I hope this clears out the air for you about `return`.

Now, about your example. You've written -

```
var number = function ( ok ){
    confirm( 8 * ok );
}

number(2);
```

In the first line, you are declaring an unnamed function, and you are assigning a reference to it to the `number` variable. If any variable holds a reference to a function, then the function can be called by placing two first brackets after the variable. That's what you are doing at the last line.

About the second example -

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

var newNumber = timesTwo (8);
confirm(newNumber);
```

Here you are again creating an unnamed function and storing its reference to `timesTwo`. This function now returns a result, so when you call it with 8, the computed value `16` gets returned by the function and is assigned to `newNumber`.

About the last one -

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

var newNumber = timesTwo (8);

if ( newNumber === 16 ) {
    confirm("success");
}
else {
    confirm("failure");
}
```

You could also rewrite it as follows -

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};

if ( timesTwo(8) === 16 ) {
    confirm("success");
}
else {
    confirm("failure");
}
```

Here, rather than storing the returned value in `newNumber` and checking its value, you are directly calling the function, whose returned value will then be checked with `16`. This is another benefit that `return`s provide - a function's returned value can be used directly in an `if` condition check, without storing it first in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be used in if statements.  Refer to this question:

[Using function's return value in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706360/using-functions-return-value-in-if-statement)